# Flask-socketio not emitting data from class methods and registered signal slots

Tags: python, signals-slots, flask-socketio

I am instantiating flas app from main class of my project, and from one of the module inside project i have created signal to emit data,using signalslot python library, and and flaskApp class is responsible for flask server, and on the same class signal is connected to slot to publish the data to connected websocket

For signalslot i am usign this library https://pypi.org/project/signalslot/

### signals.py

```
import signalslot

on_heartbeat_data_received_signal = signalslot.Signal()
```

### message.py

```
import signals.py
on_heartbeat_data_received_signal .emit(data="hello")
```

### main.py

```
class Main():
    flaskApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = Main()
```

### flaskApp.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from common.signals import on_heartbeat_data_received_signal
class FlaskApp():

    def __init__(self,config_path):
        self.logger = Logger.get_instance("FlaskApp")
        self.logger.debug("started")

         # Create an application
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'gjr39dkjn344_!67#' #todo read from yaml

        socketio.init_app(app, async_mode="threading", cors_allowed_origins="*")

        CORS(app)

        # load yml to read flask configuration from config path
        with open(config_path, "r") as yamlStream:
            try:
                self.flask_config = yaml.safe_load(yamlStream)["flask"]
            except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
                print("replace to logger")

        self.logger.info(self.flask_config["host"])
        self.logger.info(self.flask_config["port"])

        self.logger.debug("connect to signal to send to UI..")
        on_heartbeat_data_received_signal.connect(self.publish_data)

        socketio.run(app, debug=True, host=self.flask_config["host"], port=self.flask_config["port"])


        self.logger.debug("flask server is up....")

        self.logger.debug("ended")


    @socketio.on("connect")
    def websocket_connect():
        print("websocket connected...")
        # socketio.emit("response", "mesg from server") # this line is working

     #registered slot to capture data from signal
    def publish_data(self, data, **kwargs):
        self.logger.debug("started publish data to connected websocket client..")
        self.logger.debug(data)
        try:
            socketio.emit("response-data", data) #this is not emiting data
        except Exception as e:
                self.logger.error(e)

    @socketio.on("response-data")
    def handle_message(message):
        print(message)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? You seem to be logging everything so please add logs to your question.

Comment: ``socket.emit() inisde publish_data() ``method , not displaying ay error, and moreover i cannot see logs after ``socketio.run`` line ``self.logger.debug("flask server is up....")`` and ``self.logger.debug("ended")``